# Do Excel versions without Power Query / Get and Transform have access to the QueryTable Object Model?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'd like to know if a user can use a QueryTable created via VBA to retrieve data if their version of Excel doesn't have access to Power Query / Get and Transform if on Windows or Mac.

Comment: Posted here as well    https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/when-were-querytables-added-to-excel.1117951/

Comment: IIRC you can in at least 2010 Windows